# Javascript, open a link with a REL tag as if it were clicked?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to use javascript to select a link that only has an href and rel. I am trying to use the console to select a link, but the link in particular has no ID. I've tried the .click function but it seems that only works for buttons.

Comment: There are several ways to target a particular element besides its id attribute. A click event can be assigned to just about any element, not just button elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select rel attribute with this code

```
document.querySelectorAll('[rel="prev"]')[0].innerHTML = "Selected";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="https://google.com" id="a"></a>

<script>
setTimeout(function() {
document.querySelector('#a').click();
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Working nice? Or I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" rel="nofollow">link text</a>

<script>
  const a = document.querySelector('[rel="nofollow"]');
  a.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Clicked!");
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I examined this, it seems you have 2 questions here:

1. How to select an anchor element (`<a />`) that doesn't have an `id`
2. How to subsequently open the corresponding link with Javascript

The first problem has been addressed adequately in the other answers. I'd recommend reading up on [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and/or [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), depending on what context this code is being written in.

The second problem is interesting, because you mentioned using `.click` and it not working, but my tests in the browser have shown that this should work fine. For example:

```js
const anchor = document.querySelector('[href="https://google.com"]')

// opens the page according to the attributes on that anchor element
// (target blank/self etc)
anchor.click()
```

This leads me to believe you are probably just selecting the element incorrectly, so the click is on the wrong element or none at all.

I didn't check out whether browser compatibility could be playing a factor, but you could try opening the link manually, if you are sure you've selected the correct anchor element:

```js
const myAnchor = document.querySelector('[href="https://google.com"]')

openLink(myAnchor)

function openLink (anchor) {
  const url = anchor.getAttribute('href') // this will be "https://google.com"

  const target = anchor.getAttribute('target') // could be "_blank" (or nothing)

  const rel = anchor.getAttribute('rel') // could be "noopener noreferrer" (or nothing or something else)

  const windowFeatures = rel ? rel.split(' ').join(',') : undefined

  if (!target) {
    // will open link using the current browser tab
    window.open(url, '_self', windowFeatures)
  } else {
    // will open link using the target specified in the anchor tag
    window.open(url, target, windowFeatures)
  }
}
```

Check out the `window.open` API [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open).